# jquery and random.org "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: jquery, sinatra

I am having a problem requesting a random number from random.org using jQuery. When I'm using a static page and the following javascript, I don't have any issues getting random numbers. However, I am hosting a Sinatra app on Heroku (also, when running my app locally in production using Thin) I get "(website) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

```
function raffler(){

var rowCount = $('#winnerTable tr').length;

$('#winnerButton').click(function() {
    $.get("http://www.random.org/integers/?", {num: "1", min: "1", max: rowCount, col: "1", base: "10", format: "plain", rnd: "new"}, function(randNum) {
        var myNumber = randNum;
        $("#entry-" + randNum).addClass('winner');
    });
});

};
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Ajax-requests are limited by the Same Origin Policy. Unless your page is hosted on the domain `www.random.org`, you shouldn't be able to make that Ajax-request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't get how you could do that in any way. Because you shouldn't be able to do it. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is an XSS protection which blocks cross domain requests and is part of most client side scripting engines (e.g. Flash). Use the following to random number generation:

```
Math.random()
```

Comment: I'm not sure either; I can't figure out why it works when it works, and why it doesn't. I wanted to use as random number generation as possible (random.org), but I'll just have to settle for Math.random(). =] Thanks for your help.

Comment: But, if you setup a .html file on your desktop, and link to a .js file with the code that I posted above, it'll work. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well, on a quick check, random.org doesn't return *any* CORS headers. This explains, why you are not allowed to request it via Javascript from your website.

Hav you loaded your static file, where it works, locally, i.e., via `file:///` protocol? There are other security measurements on duty, and browsers usually allow cross-domain AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery YQL plugin to get result from this page.

It bypasses origin check by using Yahoo service to get content of needed page.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-yql-plugin

But it is very complicated way. Why don't you use Math.random() ?